# Replacing class instance inside class

Tags: c#, class, runtime, this

I have abstract class `A` which can serialize itself to and from `byte[]`.

Another class `C` is parameterized with type `T` which should be or inherit from `A` and have parameterless constructor. `C` need to convert both ways between `T` and `byte[]`.

```
Class C <T> where T : A, new() { ... }
```

The problem is: how to get `T` from `byte[]`?

I can't use some static method from `A`, because I can't override it. I can't call `T(byte[])`, because C# doesn't allow it.

The only way I found is to create instance of `T` and call some method overridden from `A`, i.e:

```
byte[] bytes; // some byte table
T someT = new T();
T.LoadFromBytes(bytes);
```

I would work, but in many cases I can only convert from bytes to new object of `T`.
Is there any better solution or any way to do sth like:

```
public class SomeTClass : A
{
    public SomeTClass(){...}
    public void LoadFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        SomeTClass newT = Sth(bytes); /* new instance of SomeTClass
                                         is created from bytes */
        this = newT; /* can't do this, but I need to replace
                        current instance with the new one */
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of serialization are you using? It's pretty important...

Comment: Your second sentence is a bit confusing, `C` needs to be `T` but then you constrain is to `A`.

Comment: Have you got a class factory with every type req'd having an instance in it?

Comment: So `Sth` is a class iheriting from `SomeTClass`?

Comment: @james It can't be important. Classes derived from `A` can implement they own serialization.

Comment: @GrantThomas I have base class `A`. It could be interface for this purpose. Then I have class C parameterized with any class derived from A.

Comment: @Ari If they can implement their own serialization then I don't see where your problem is? I thought your issue was you were using the base method to convert to `byte[]` but needed to then deserialize to `T`, not back to `A`.

Comment: @Aschratt `Sth` is some not important, or not known code which would magically convert `byte[]` to `SomeTClass`.

Comment: @James I don't know how to implement deserializing method when all I can do is to convert `byte[]` to new object of my type. In example `Sth` is code, which would create new object of type `SomeTClass`, but I need this new object to replace current instance.

Comment: So just to clarify, you have a `byte[]` which you want to convert to type `T` and replace the internal instance of `A`?

Comment: @James No, I have `byte[]` and I want to convert it to `T`, but only `T` knows, how to convert `byte[]` to `T`.

Comment: @Ari Ok I see. The best way is what you have already suggested (given that `T` knows how to deal with `byte[]`). In your `LoadFromBytes` you wouldn't replace the instance you would set all the properties etc. When you say "*but I need to replace the current instance with the new one*" what's your use case for that?

Comment: @James I mean in most cases I would use external deserializers, which would return new object of given class. I don't want to manually replace all fields from old one to new one. It is waste of time to write such code for all methods.

Comment: @Ari well there is always the option of using reflection to map your properties across. Alternatively, if you don't mind using a 3rd party lib there is always tools like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)/[ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) which were built for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, but I don't like code I created.

The idea is to parameterized class A with T and create abstract method, which would be static, if it weren't be used from template type:

```
public abstract class A <T>
{
    public abstract byte[] Serialize();
    public abstract T Deserialize(byte[]); //should be static
}
```

Class `C` has new reguirement:

```
public class C <T> where T : A <T>
{
    someMethod(...)
    {
        ...
        byte[] bytes; // some bytes
        T = new T().Deserialize(bytes); // should be T.Deserialize(bytes)
        ...
    }
}
```

And some `T` implementation:

```
public class SomeTClass : A<SomeTClass>
{
    public SomeTClass Deserialize(byte[])
    {
        //deserialization code
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is a better way, please provide.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the `UpdateReference` method and deserialization implementation. I think you should make your deserialization method as `farbic method`. It should takes `byte[]` as input parameter and return new instance of type you need.
Is it what you want?

```
class C <T> where T : IA, new()
{
  public T Data { get; set; }
  .....

  public UpdateReference()
  {
    byte[] data = GetBytesFromSomewhere();
    Data = AImpl.Deserialize(data);

    Data.UserfulMethod();
    Data.AnotherUserfulMethod();

    data = GetBytesFromSomewhere();
    Data = AImpl.Deserialize(data)

    Data.UserfulMethod();
    Data.AnotherUserfulMethod();
  }
}

public interface IA
{
  public byte[] Serialize();
  public A Deserialize(byte[] data);

  public string UsefuleMethod1();
  public int AnotherUsefulMethod();
}

public class AImpl : IA
{
  public byte[] Serialize()
  {
    //Concrete implementation serialization
  }

  public static IA Deserialize(byte[] data)
  {
    //Concrete implementation deserialization
  }
}
```

Comment: In your code only `AImpl` is allowed to be used as IA. I mean, all classes derived from `IA` could have their own [de]serializer.

Comment: How do you expecting your code should decided which class to deserialize from `byte[]`? for example, you have AImpl1, AImpl2 and AImpl3. You code only knows about `byte[]` - whose deserialization method should be called?

Comment: You may prepend you `byte[]` with some kind of marker byte, convert interface to abstract class with fabric method. An this metho will analyse marker byte and calls corresponding deserializer.

Comment: Instance of `C` has actual class as `T` and can use its methods derived from `A`. The problem is that it can't use static methods from `T`. If it could, problem would by easily solvable by static method in `T` getting `byte[]` and returning `T` (there is no problem to create such method)